# Pymongo & Django query invalid JSON

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

Im trying to create a JSON result with Pymongo , Mongodb and Django. I have created a Django view that contains a pymongo query and want to return the results in json. However, the results produced arent valid json (according to jsonlint)

Here is my django view.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pymongo
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json
from bson import json_util

#setup database connection
try:
    conn = pymongo.Connection()
    db = conn.mydatabase
except:
    print('Error: Unable to connect to database.')
    conn = None

def querypeople(request):
    result = db.people.find({}).sort('name')
    json_docs = []
    for doc in result:
        json_doc = json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        json_docs.append(json_doc)
    return HttpResponse(json_docs, content_type='application/json')
```

Which produces this output. (Notice commas missing between each document and [  ] should be enclosing the entire result. This makes it invalid JSON.) What am i doing wrong?

> "_id": {
>           "$oid": "50c596ab2b9afbbc85ed202a"
>       }, 
>       "date_added": {
>           "$date": 1355126443473
>       }, 
>       "name": "Al Landon"
>   }{
>       "_id": {
>           "$oid": "50c5b9d92b9afbc3f1e7c90c"
>       }, 
>       "company": "Corrs", 
>       "date_added": {
>           "$date": 1355135449179
>       }, 
>       "name": "Andrew Lumsden", 
>       "title": "A Partner"

Comment: these are somehow two steps of serializing. you employ json.dumps on every list element. Am I assuming correctly, that your desired json should look like this: {"obj": [{"_id": {"$oid": "12323"},"date_added": {"$date": 1355126443473},"name": "Al Landon"},{"_id": {"$oid": "50c5b9d92b9afbc3f1e7c90c"},"company": "Corrs","date_added": {"$date": 1355135449179},"name": "Andrew Lumsden","title": "A Partner"}]}

Comment: that is correct, that is how my desired json should look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you return with response list, not json string. Try:

```
json_docs = json.dumps(list(result), default=json_util.default, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```